# Multiplication of linear maps $S$ and $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$ and $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ them we define $ST \in \mathcal{L}(U,W)$ by $$(ST)(v)= S(Tv) \text{ for } v \in U.$$ Verify that the composition $S \circ T$ of functions as defined above is linear.

Is the following verification correct?

$\begin{align} (ST)(v+w) &= S(Tv+Tw) \\&=(ST)(v) + (ST)(w) \\ (ST)(av) &= aS(Tv) \\&= a(ST)(v)\end{align}$

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.

Comment: No, it is incomplete; I mean, if you are being asked to show this explicitly, steps should be justified, and here steps are skipped. (I mention this here to counter the other comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be a little more complete, insert a couple of intermediate equalities.

$$\begin{align} (ST)(v+w) 
&= S(T(v + w))\\
&= S(Tv+Tw) \\
&=(ST)(v) + (ST)(w)
\end{align}
$$

\begin{align}
(ST)(av) &= S(T(av))\\&=S(aT(v))\\
&= aS(Tv) \\&= a(ST)(v)
\end{align}

Your logic looks just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the added clarification

Comment: Happy to be of service.  Best of luck in your study of linear algebra. It is a very cool subject.

Comment: Yeah, it is very interesting so far. My previous math classes have mainly been computational type math classes, so it is nice to get to a taste for some more abstract stuff. I'm really looking forward to abstract algebra as well!

Comment: You are in for a great intellectual adventure. Prepare to savoor.